# Java EE Eclipse project structure

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a Java Maven Project in Eclipse and I have put it into GIT.

My project ist a  Web-Project and now I have taken a look at the project structure in the "Project Explorer" in Eclipse. It is like this:

[image]

So as you can see I have two times the src/main/java and src/test/java folder but why do I do not have the src/main/resources folder in the upper section?
And what is the difference between the two folders, why do I have two times src/main/java and only one time src/main/resources or src/main/webapp?

Answer (score 1):

The folders `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are configured as source folders in eclipse, this is why they are shown at the top.

All other folders, like `src/main/webapp`, are *not* configured as source folders. So they are displayed only at the bottom, where eclipse shows the directory structure of your project.

When you have a look in your filesystem, you will notice `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` exist only once, despite eclipse showing it twice. This is simply eclipse giving you another view to the folders you need most often.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer. But if I would like to change something in my web.xml or persistence.xml which is not shown in the source folder area I can modify it directly in the folder structure below and it has not to be in the upper "source folder" area?

Comment: You can edit all files either in the bottom (directory structure) area or in the top (source folder) area. All changes will be synced (since the file is only once in the file system)